# Run parallel processes in node js to handle SQS messages

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

sqs allow MaxNumberOfMessages = 10

*("The maximum number of messages to return. Amazon SQS never returns more messages than this value but may return fewer. ")*

to fetch messages at once, So is there any way we can run multiple parallel processes
in nodejs which can handle many sqs messages.

Any npm package available for that?

Comment: How are you running node.js, and why is it not on Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Async might not be the right option as parallel operations are really not run parallel on them.

https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback
*parallel(tasks, [callback])
Run the tasks collection of functions in parallel, without waiting until the previous function has completed. If any of the functions pass an error to its callback, the main callback is immediately called with the value of the error. Once the tasks have completed, the results are passed to the final callback as an array.
Note: parallel is about kicking-off I/O tasks in parallel, not about parallel execution of code. If your tasks do not use any timers or perform any I/O, they will actually be executed in series. Any synchronous setup sections for each task will happen one after the other. JavaScript remains single-threaded.
It is also possible to use an object instead of an array. Each property will be run as a function and the results will be passed to the final callback as an object instead of an array. This can be a more readable way of handling results from parallel.*

But you can use background threads , worker threads to run these tasks in parallel,But not sure if this would solve ur issue fully.

Answer (score 0):

You can spin up multiple processes, but node is meant for leveraging the max out of the available core with a single processes. Creating more processes will not necessarily make the overall throughput much higher.
If you have a multicore machine, generally it is advisable to have one process per core.

The AWS Javascript SDK for SQS works asynchronously, i.e the process will continue to fetch more messages when I/O is happening for the first fetch.
Unless you are making the process synchronous by waiting, the process will retrieve messages from SQS continuously.

Comment: Lets assume we can fetch max 10 message from sqs per second. So we can fetch (3600 *10) = 36000 messages per hour. So i want to create multiple parallel process. So as many messages get fetched and handle.

Comment: Node is designed to be single threaded. And with 10 processes also you will be limited by how much io throughput is available on the machine. In this case a single node process should be able to fetch 36000 messages.